# Visualizing my popt outputs yield a straight line, I want to visualize the popt output to make sure its correct. I am beginner

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, exponential, scipy-optimize

My popt variables output a straight vertical line (please see link to [visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8DwQ.png)). I want to find the correct exponential line of best fit of my data

I had done the exponential in excel first which yielded the [desired visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K4Fv.png) but gave an inaccurate formula of 712e^0.0001*x.

I want to visualize the popt values similarly to the [desired visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K4Fv.png) in excel to make sure my popt values made sense visually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


plot = plt.scatter(df.No_of_patients, df.No_of_booked_app)
plt.xlabel("No_of_patients")
plt.ylabel("No_of_booked_app")
plt.xlim(-500, 16000)
plt.ylim(-1000, 7000)
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8, 9, 10]
y1 = [2, 4, ,8 , 12, 20, 35, 40, 55, 70, 90]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(x1, y1), columns = ['x1', 'y1'] )



def func(x, a, b, p0=None):
   return a*np.exp(b*x)

x = df.x1
y = df.y1


popt, popcov = curve_fit(func,  x,  y, p0=[1,0], maxfev = 5000)



best_fit = plt.plot(func(x,*popt), 'y')
```

[current_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8DwQ.png)

This is my desired output:

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K4Fv.png)

Comment: Why do you say that the Excel gave you bad results? What criteria are you using to determine that?

Comment: Why do you make it into a dataframe and never use it?

Comment: I chose points that were really close, practically on on the line and inputted into the formula excel gave me and it was very different

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added the data frame  if was needed I wasn't sure what the solution would be. Though it could cut out a step

Comment: It's counter-productive if you have to unpack it right in the next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the x-variable to the plot command. So just use the following where you pass `x` and use `o` as the market symbol

```
best_fit = plt.plot(x, func(x,*popt), 'yo')
```